# Podcast app with Google Reader integration (Google Listen alternative)

Tags: applications, sync, podcast, google-reader

I'm looking for a podcast app that would have the same features as Google Listen without the buggyness...

From what I've seen, most apps that feature "Google Reader integration" only offer importing, not syncing.

Is there an app out there that does podcasts and only podcasts, that I could simply point to my Google Listen folder in Google Reader, and have it sync subscriptions and read status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of apps in Android Market which offer import from your Google Reader subscriptions. The best of them [according to Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5811101/five-best-mobile-podcast-catchers) is [DoggCatcher Podcast Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.snoggdoggler.android.applications.doggcatcher.v1_0). [BeyondPod Podcast Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.beyondpod) also offers import from Google Reader. But [ACast](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mathias.android.acast)'s description claims that the app has integration with Google Reader, not just import *(sorry, can't test it myself, this app crashed for me)*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I had tested all apps you mention except ACast, which seems to do the trick! Only thing it doesn't seem to do is map "delete" to "unsubscribe" for feeds in GReader, but that's not that much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to double-check on the reality of the sync/import part of the question, but you may want to look at [BeyondPod](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.beyondpod&feature=search_result). It claims that it will sync read/unread status, but I've not used that capacity. I've used it for years (on WinMo long before Android was available on a phone) and have loved using it.

Comment: I've used BeyondPod too and found that it's "sync" feature was lacking, at least at the feed level.